# Strings and user input C++

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to read an integer *n* from the user, which is the followed by *n* words, and then what follows after that is a sequence of words and punctuation terminated by the word END. For example:

```
2 foo d  
foo is just food without the d . END
```

The *n* words are to be "redacted" from the second line. So it would show up as:

```
*** is just food without the * .
```

I think I can figure out the redacting part. I just cannot seem to figure out how to read the words in... any help is much appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n;
cin >> n;

string *redact = new string[n]
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    cin >> redact[i] // this part works!

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code sample doesn't even compile.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ missing `;` ... panic?

Comment: @AntiHeadshot No panic, just stated the fact. OP should post their _real_ code.

Answer (score 2):

Following code will cater the purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

int main()
{
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;

  std::set<std::string> redact;
  std::string word;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    std::cin >> word;
    redact.insert(word);
  }
 while( std::cin>> word && word != "END" )
 { 
     if ( redact.find(word) == redact.end() )
        std::cout<<word<<' ';
 }
 std::cout<<'\n';
return 0;
}
```

I believe you are a learning C++, please note a point use `typesafe`, `bound-safe` and `scope-safe` C++.

So, no `new` `delete` unless you can call yourself an `adept`. Use the algorithms and containers provided by C++, instead of inventing your own.